# Contenteditable deletes and edit the icon in field too

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, contenteditable

I am using contenteditable in my table, and each td when created using Javascript is set `contenteditable="true"`.

The problem is I want to add an ICON in the field that says 'TOTAL', and allow the user to change data, but with contenteditable its even allowing them to edit/delete the icon!

I want the icon to stay there and not edit or change. Is there any way to fix span or icon in editable td using JavaScript or CSS?

Example:

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td contenteditable="true"><span>$</span>887</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You could update your example to show the icon as well, because you complain about an issue that's not reproducible in your example.

Comment: In the example, i have Used <span>$</span>. Taking $ here as icon in the example, since <span> and <i> are widely used for icon.

Comment: Could you make the $ it's own td for the icon, and make it so that part isn't editable?

Comment: Zack i tried doing it but doesnt look good. The table data look seperated and far from eachother even though i am using table with No Cell or grid.

Answer (score 1):

Move the contenteditable to another span that doesn't include the image:

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>TOTAL</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>$<span contenteditable="true">887</span></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```